# OpenVPN двойное шифрование возможно?

Tags: linux, шифрование, openvpn, криптография

Есть впн сервер, он подвключен к другому впн, последний смотрит на  ресурс.

Понятно, что на выходе весь трафик расшифровывается, но он так же расшифровывается и на каждом сервере.

То есть, у нас получается, что трафик шифруется после первого сервера не поверх впн'а?

И у нас цепочка, такая - трафик шифруется с клиента до первого сервера, там он расшифровывается и заново зашифровывается, и получается что  звено  впн1-впн2 имеет  не двойное шифрование, верно?

Если верно, то как можно сделать чтобы было двойное(тройное, квадро, и т.д.) шифрование?  не туннелями же ssh?

Или на выходном сервере тоже нужно поднимать клиент входного сервера, на входном сервере разрешать **client-to-client**, и тогда я подключаясь к первому серверу пробрасываюсь на выходной, который уже имеет канал шифрования?

В таком случае ,все расшифруется на выходном и получим как раз двойное шифрование?

Какие варианты?

Используется OpenVPN, ключи генерируются с помощью easy-rsa 3.1, Сервера CentOS7(x64), пробросы через iptables.